# How many 2-adic integers $x$ satisfy $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac {a_i}n=\log_2(3)$ (modulo addition with eventually zero sequences)?

Tags: logarithms, p-adic-number-theory, quotient-spaces

Is there a 2-adic integer $x$ satisfying $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^n \frac {a_i}n=\log_3(2)$?

Let $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^ia_i:a_i\in\{0,1\}$$ represent the 2-adic integers.

Let $f:\Bbb Z_2\to\Bbb R$ be given by: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg( \frac1n \sum_{i=0}^n a_i \bigg)$$

**Question**

Is there a 2-adic integer satisfying $f(x)=\log_3(2)$?

Obviously if there is one, there are infinitely many obtained by $Y+x$ where $Y$ is the set of eventually zero 2-adic sequences.

How unique is the solution in $\Bbb Z_2/Y$ where the quotient is taken additively or multiplicatively?

I've given $Y$ as the set of eventually zero 2-adic sequences, but how large is the superset of $Y$ that contains binary strings which leave $f(x)$ unchanged when added to or multiplied by $x$?  I.e. $\overline Y=\{y\in\Bbb Z_2:f(x+y)=f(x)=\log_3(2)\}$

**Conjecture**

Multiplication with $2^p3^q$ leaves $f(x)=\log_3(2)$ unchanged.

**Attempt**

I think $x$ can be constructed by induction starting with zero and adding $2^{m+1}$ to the partial sum for each $m$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^m\frac{a_i}m<\log_3(2)$

As regards the size or structure of the set $Y$ that can leave the property unchanged, I'm unsure how to approach this but have the following thoughts if we assume first that $f(x)=log_3(2):

- Addition with any number having repeating zeroes will fix $f$
- Multiplication by $2$ obviously fixes $f$
- Subsequences of $x$ which are truncations from the right must have the same property.
- Multiplication by $3$ may fix $f$ because of an unusual symmetry of the binary digits of $3^m:m\in\Bbb Z$ whereby $3^{-n}$ is pseudo-palindromic.

Comment: Note that e.g. if $a_i= \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } i =17^k \\ 0 \text{ else} \end{cases}$, we also have $f(x)=0$. -- Also, I don't understand what you mean by "subsequences of $x$ must have the same property". As long as the sequence $(a_i)_i$ contains infinitely many $1$'s and infinitely many $0$'s, for any given value $0 \le y\le 1$ I can find subsequences for which the density of $1$'s is $y$.

Comment: Also, if you believe that $f(x+z)=f(x)$ for any $2$-adic number $z$ whose sequence $a_i$ is eventually $0$, that's wrong. Consider $x=-1= (111111...)$ and $z=1 = (100000...)$. The function $f$ does not behave well w.r.t. $2$-adic addition, and I doubt it behaves well w.r.t. to any structure on the set of binary strings that is closely related to viewing them as $2$-adic integers.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg thanks for highlighting the typos. Re addition, I don't have $\overline1_2=-1$ is eventually zero. I have $\overline01_2=1$ is eventually zero. Then I only intended to claim addition with $1$ would fix the property $f(x+1)=\log_3(2)$ if it were true that $f(x)=\log_3(2)$.  I'll think for a moment on your 2nd comment but I have made a mistake, I only meant subsequences which are truncations of the original so I need to think how to reword that.

Comment: Well I've come to believe that $f(x+Y)=f(x)$ but only if $x$ does not end in a string of $1$'s like in my above counterexample. Re multiplication with $3$, is not $f(-\frac13)=1/2$ but $f(-1)=1$, and more generally $f(\frac{1}{1-2^n})= 1/n$ but $f(\frac{3}{1-2^n})= 2/n$ for all $n\ge 2$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg re your last comment, first part, I agree, thank-you. 2nd part not only does that appear to check out I can instantly give a conjecture that combines it with Greg Martin's initial result below, suggesting $f(3T)=2f(T)\pmod1$

Comment: Neat. I can see roughly where $f(3x)=2f(x)$ mod $\mathbb Z$ might come from, and have not found a counterexample, but a rigorous proof would be interesting to see; also, possible generalisations like $f((2^{n}-1)x) \stackrel{?}= nx$ mod $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg The fact that $T(x+2x)=T(x+x/2)$ kinda says it doesn't matter whether you add a copy bit-shifted left or add a copy bit shifted right.  I suspect this left-right symmetry somehow combines with my other recent question which sends 2-adic sequences to $[0,1]$ by reversing them.  That has left-right symmetry too, wherein there are two isomorphic additions modulo $1$ on $[0,1]$.  One is conventional addition mod $1$ with carries to the left and the other is the morphed 2-adic addition with carries to the right. Not sure how $[0,1]\neq[0,1)$ affects things.

Comment: I'd like to point out though -- has not been mentioned so far -- that $f$ is not actually well-defined on "most" irrational numbers. E.g. take $a_i = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } 2^{4n} \le i \le 2^{4n+2} \\ 0 \text{ else } \end{cases}$, if I'm not mistaken the "density" should oscillate between 1/4 and 3/4 here. One could always take a lim inf or lim sup of course.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg your ingenuity at coming up with counterexamples never ceases to amaze me. I guess it's actually a surjection onto sequences of values in $[0,1]$ then? Something isomorphic to $C^\Bbb N$ with $C$ the Cantor set. But converges in $[0,1]$ for all rational inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $2$-adic integer
$$
T = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{\lfloor k/ \log_32\rfloor}
$$
does the trick. Empirically, the multiple $3T$ has a far different density of $1$s, around 26.2% (whereas $\log_32$ is approximately 63.1%).

Comment: Thanks Greg. I think this is the solution proposed in the question, expressed better!  Thank-you also for the empirical result.

Comment: Are you able to confirrm whether $f(3T)=2f(T)\pmod1$?  Empirically I mean.