# When does the asymptotic density of a set in the natural numbers not exist?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\displaystyle d(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\# (A\cap[1,n])}n$ be the asymptotic density of $A$ in the natural numbers.

I came across a statement saying that **such that the limit exists** it measures the asymptotic density of $A$ in the natural numbers.  That looks straightforward, except for "**such that the limit exists**".  $d$ would appear on first sight to be a function on $\Bbb R$ bounded by $[0,1]$
When may a limit not exist?  Are there textbook examples?

**My attempt**

It seems hard to come up with a well-defined set of natural numbers such that $A$ does not exist, but I notice that $A$ is not necessarily a subset of the natural numbers, it's a subset of the positive real line.  I can only speculate that opening up to an uncountable set opens up the possibility of some examples from set theory perhaps drawn from $\Bbb R$ using the axiom of choice.  For example I can see that any set of representatives of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Q$ will have zero density up to a point and then may have density $1/n$ at some point, if the sole representative drawn from $\Bbb Q$ is within $\Bbb N$.  Maybe that's got something to do with the answer?

Comment: It is possible to construct sets with upper density $\alpha$ and lower density $\beta$ for any $0\le\beta\le\alpha\le1$. In particular, the limit doesn’t exist if $\alpha\neq\beta$

Comment: Sorry @FShrike I understand your statement but its significance to the question goes over my head.

Comment: The limit exists if and only if the liminf equals the limsup. My comment states that the liminf and limsup can be arbitrarily far apart (in the bounds $[0,1]$) as you like, for the same set, so there are myriad constructions of sets for which the limit doesn’t exist. I will try and procure a link

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4413104/815585

Comment: @FShrike aha the penny drops, so if $f(n):\Bbb N\to\{0,1\}$ indicates membership of $n$ in $A$, and $A$'s sequence is say $100111000000111111111111...$, with each constant sequence equally long as the entire sequence preceding it, this oscillates within bounds either side of $1/2$, correct?

Comment: I think it would have upper density $2/3$ and lower density $1/3$ but I haven't proven this. But that's the idea anyway @samerivertwice I am confident its asymptotic natural density does not exist as a single limit

Comment: @FShrike it would have the property that if one exchanged $1$'s for $0$'s the limits would be exchanged, and since that is the case for exchanging $-\frac13=\overline{01}_2,-\frac23=\overline{10}_2$ I'm inclined to trust your judgement.

Comment: I will get back to you with a proof later, if I can figure it out. We need to meddle with triangle numbers

Comment: Let $A = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4 \cup A_5 \cup \cdots $ where $A_1 = \{10, 11, \ldots, 10^{10}\} = \{10^{10^0}, 10^{10^0}+1, \ldots, 10^{10^1}\}$ and $A_2 = \{10^{10^2}, 10^{10^2} + 1, \ldots, 10^{10^3}\}$ and $A_3 = \{10^{10^4}, 10^{10^4} + 1, \ldots, 10^{10^5}\}$ and $A_4 = \{10^{10^6}, 10^{10^6} + 1, \ldots, 10^{10^7}\}$ and $A_5 = \{10^{10^8}, 10^{10^8} + 1, \ldots, 10^{10^9}\}$ and so on in the same manner. Then for any $\epsilon > 0,$ there will be infinitely many values of $n$ such that $\frac{\# (A\,\cap \,[1,n])}{n} < \epsilon$ **(continued)**

Comment: and infinitely many values of $n$ such that $\frac{\# (A\,\cap \,[1,n])}{n} > 1 - \epsilon$ (i.e. the limit fails to exist in a rather spectacular way). Incidentally, the "widths" of the sets $A_1,\,A_2,\,\ldots$ increases far more rapidly than needed for what I wanted, but I chose the widths so that there would be no doubt. And if there is doubt, just increase the pace of the width growths to whatever you feel comfortable with having no doubt about the conclusion.

Comment: @FShrike: Given an infinite subset $A$ of the positive integers, let $\{x_n\}_A$ be the sequence whose $n$'th term is $\frac{\# (A\,\cap \,[1,n])}{n}.$ Then I believe there exists a subset $B$ of the positive integers such that the set of all subsequence limits of $\{x_n\}_B$ is equal to the closed interval $[0,1].$ Note that any such set $B$ has the property that its lower density is $0$ and its upper density is $1,$ but this is only a small way towards how badly the limit fails to exist for such an example. **(continued)**

Comment: I don't have time now to look for a reference or to carefully go though an example, but here's a sketch for how this can be done. First, rather than trying to explicitly get every real number in the unit interval as a subsequence limit (continuum many subsequence limits needed), it is enough to find an example in which every rational number in the open interval $(0,1)$ is a subsequence limit, since the set of subsequence limits of a (bounded) sequence is always a closed set (you can probably find this last result proved several times in MSE). **(continued)**

Comment: So enumerate the rationals in $(0,1)$ as $r_1,\,r_2,\,\ldots$ and define $B$ so the density after a while is within $10^{-1}$ of $r_1$ and then at some point after this the density is within $10^{-2}$ of $r_2$ and then at some point after this the density is within $10^{-3}$ of $r_1$ and then at some point after this the density is within $10^{-4}$ of $r_2$ and then at some point after this the density is within $10^{-5}$ of $r_3$ and then at some point after this the density is within $10^{-6}$ of $r_1$ and so on **(continued)**

Comment: (successively decrease the exponent of $10$ while revisiting $r_1$ infinitely often and revisiting $r_2$ infinitely often and revisiting $r_3$ infinitely often, etc.).

Comment: Interest comments, @DaveL.Renfro , you could well post that as a supplementary answer!

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro your methods in these comments remind me of Cantor normal form and Goodstein's theorem. I wonder if that form can be adapted to build $A$ such that limits fail to exist.

Comment: Just for the record, I brought up the idea to all such counterexamples in my last comment (July 18, 2020) to your question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3758900/96384.

Comment: Thanks @TorstenSchoeneberg I didn't get the relevance when I fiest read those comments, a fact which I put down to my own ineptitude. Nevertheless the penny dropped after FSHrike's comment.